# No module named 'cnn_models'

Tags: python, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

```
import json
from typing_extensions import dataclass_transform
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from cnn_models.alexnet import AlexNet
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OX'] = 'TRUE'


def main():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    data_transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5))])

        # load image
    img_path = "C:\\code\\python\\data pratice\\train\\ants_image\\392382602_1b7bed32fa.jpg"
    assert os.path.exist(img_path), "file: '{}' dose not exist.".format(img_path)
    img = Image.open(img_path)

    plt.imshow(img)
    img = data_transform(img)
    img = torch.unsqueeze(img,dim=0)
    json_path = 'C:\\code\\python\\data pratice\\class_indices.json'
    assert os.path.exists(json_path),"file: '{}' dose not exist.".format(json_path)

    json_file = open(json_path,"r")
    class_indict = json.load(json_file)

    model = AlexNet(num_classes=5).to(device)

    weight_path = "C:\\code\\python\\checkpoints\\alex\\alex_animals.pth"
    assert os.path.exists(weight_path), "file: '{}' dose not exist.".format(weight_path)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_path))

    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
            output = torch.squeeze(model(img.to(device))).cpu()
            predict = torch.softmax(output,dim=0)
            predict_cla = torch.argmax(predict).numpy()

    print_res = "class: {}   prob : {:.3}".format(class_indict[str(predict_cla)],
                                                     predict[predict_cla].numpy())
    plt.title(print_res)
    for i in range(len(predict)):
            print("class: {:10}   prob: {:.3}".format(class_indict[str[i]],
                                                      predict[i].numpy()))
    plt.show()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```